# Can we intersect coalgebras?

Tags: coalgebras

Let $k$ be a commutative ring, which I am unwilling to assume is a field, and suppose $(C_i)$ is a collection of coassociative $k$-subcoalgebras<sup>1</sup> of a coassociative $k$-coalgebra $C$. ***Is there always a coalgebra structure on the $k$-submodule $\bigcap C_i$ making it a subcoalgebra of $C$?***

If not, is there some reasonable hypothesis (cocompleteness, grading, ...) on $C$ or the submodules $C_i$ guaranteeing it?

In the case $k$ is indeed a field, there is the standard proof summing annihilator ideals in the dual algebra $C^*$, but that technique doesn't seem to be available in the general case.

---

<sup>1</sup> This means, each $C_i$ is a both a coalgebra in some way and a $k$-submodule of $C$ such that $C_i \hookrightarrow C$ is a coalgebra map, the issue with a less finicky definition being that $C_i \otimes_k C_i \to C \otimes_k C$ isn't in general an injection.

Comment: Just as quotients of a $k$-algebra $A$ are the same thing as quotients of $A$ considered as an $(A,A)$-bimodule, so also by duality, subcoalgebras of a $k$-coalgebra $C$ should be the same thing as "subbicomodules" of $C$ considered as a $(C,C)$-bicomodule.